# How to access a JSON Array response using JsonPath?

Tags: json, rest, jsonpath, rest-assured

How to handle when REST service response is returned as Json Array:  for e.g:

```
[{"boolField":true,"intField":991, "StringField":"SampleString"},
 {"boolField":false, "intField":998, "StringField": "SampleString2"}]";
```

All the blogs & examples I have seen didn't deal with the scenario mentioned above. For example, I went through http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/ expression syntax, but couldn't locate the solution.

For example the following json, if I want to get all the authors, I can use `$.store.book[*].author`  or `$..author`

```
{ "store": {
    "book": [ 
      { "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price": 8.95
      },
      { "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 12.99
      }]}
}
```

However, if the REST service response is returned like below, then how to get all authors from the list

```
[
  { "category": "reference",
    "author": "Nigel Rees",
    "title": "Sayings of the Century",
    "price": 8.95
  },
  { "category": "fiction",
    "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
    "title": "Sword of Honour",
    "price": 12.99
   }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$..author` will retrieve all of the authors.

In general when your root object is an array, you can think of the `$` as an array and do things like `$[0]` to inspect the first item (You'll still get an array back however).

Comment: I tested it at https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/ and got the array of authors back, what results do you get?

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The parameter "author" was used but not defined. Define parameters using the JsonPath.params(...) function` when I use `$..author`.  If i use `$.author`  an empty `[]` is returned. If I use `$` alone, I am getting the list.

Comment: I tried in jsonpath.curiousconcept.com, and it resulted in `An unknown error has occured`. I am at least able to proceed and not blocked, as I am getting `$`  result as list.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `[0].author` worked (I left out the $).